# Google Maps doesn't load on Bootstrap 3 with a tab on modal

Tags: javascript, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working with Bootstrap using tabs into a modal, in the second tab I have a div for Google Maps. Works perfectly, only by Google Maps that I used on Bootstrap tab inside a modal. The problem is that doesn't show the map, only the Google on the corner and nothing else.

I tried to use

```
$('#dlgProductDetail').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        });
```

And

```
$('a[href="#detailProductLocation"]').on('shown', function (e) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        });
```

This is my modal

```
<div class="modal" id="modalShowDetail" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="titleChange"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="font-size: 14px;">
                <!-- pestanias de edicion -->
                <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#detailProductGral" data-toggle="tab">General</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#detailProductLocation" data-toggle="tab">Location</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <!-- pestania general -->
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="detailProductGral">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="txtDetailProduct">Autoservicio:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="5" id="txtDetailProduct">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- pestania ubicacion -->
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="detailProductLocation">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="txtDetailProductAddress">Address:</label>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" id="txtDetailProductAddress" style="height: 33px;"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div id="prodcut_map" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="txtDetailProductLatitude">Latitud:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="30" id="txtDetailProductLatitude" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="txtDetailProductLongitude">Longitud:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="30" id="txtDetailProductLongitude" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-flat" id="btnCancelGralProduct">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my script

```
var map;
var markers = [];

function initMap () {
    mexico_center = { lat: 22.841611, lng: -102.109821 };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('product_map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: mexico_center,
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });
}
```

Comment: check your console tab, there must be some errors

Comment: @MuhammadAkberKhan Hello,I checked the console and nothing. I tried to refresh but nothing, in other questions I saw that I need to refresh the map

Comment: It's better to initialize Google Maps only when the map-div is visible, and at full size.  Can you show some code of the tabs you use?  Maybe try to trigger initMap() when the client clicks on the "map" tab (only once of course)

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay Hi, I edit the question and add the modal and my script, thanks for all

Comment: Replace resize action with `initMap();` to completely rebuild it on opening.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan It works, but if the tab is no active and then click the tab, doesn't work

Comment: You have to rebuild it on tab click as well. You can't build a map without having it shown, just fix the code to meet that.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan thanks for your help man, it works, I'm testing a little more but is working fine. Thanks a lot